# Named replaces in strings with Mako

Tags: python, mako

When creating a template in Mako, I would need to write things like : `${_('Hello, %(fname)s %(lname)s') % {'fname':'John','lname':'Doe'}}`

I keep getting *SyntaxException: (SyntaxError) unexpected EOF while parsing* when writing that. Is there wny way to do the same ?

`${_('Hello, %s %s') % ('John', 'Doe')}` works, but it does not allow to change the order of the replacements when changing language, if needed.

Thanks.

Comment: I usually get unexpected EOF or EOL when I have unmatched quotes, parentheses, brackets, and/or braces.

Comment: I do, too. But I checked many times, and everything seems correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the new Python string formatting:

```
>>> "{foo} {bar}".format(foo="foo", bar="bar")
'foo bar'
>>> "{foo} {bar}".format(**{"foo": "Hello", "bar": "World!"})
'Hello World!'
```

It looks nicer and is futureproof.

Answer (score 2):

Using `{}` inside Mako's `${}` is complicated; apparently Mako stops parsing the expression after finding the first `}`.  A possible workaround is to use `dict()` instead of `{}`:

```
${_('Hello, %(fname)s %(lname)s') % dict(fname='John', lname='Doe')}
```